# How to implement FAL3 requirements in Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity, nist

We have a SAML architecture where we (as the service provider/RP), allow the user to authenticate using their Microsoft account. The assertion is digitally signed by Microsoft (FAL1) and we have an encryption option as well (FAL2). According to NIST (https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63-3.html),

```
FAL3: FAL3 requires the subscriber to present proof of possession of a cryptographic key referenced in the assertion along with the assertion itself. The assertion must be signed using approved cryptography and encrypted to the RP using approved cryptography.
```

What would be an example of such a cryptographic key? In particular, how would I get azure's assertion to reference said key?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63c.html#holderofkey,

> The key MAY be a symmetric key or a public key that corresponds to a private key.

I'm not familiar with Azure AD. Presumably there would be a way to pull public key from the user's record and include that as a custom claim in the authentication assertion. Similarly, for symmetric keys, presumably there would be a way to retrieve the symmetric key from the user record, and then specify fingerprint or keyID as a custom claim in the authentication assertion.

I'd start by looking here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims or here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/saml-claims-customization